# A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property

Tags: wpf, binding

I've a read only property I need to display in a textbox, and getting this error at runtime. I've set `IsEnabled="False"`, `IsReadOnly="True"` - no luck.
Other searches say the readonly should fix it, but not for me.
I've got an ugly workaround by adding a dummy setter...

Comment: If you do want two way binding, the property setter must be public. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773150/invalidoperationexception-a-twoway-or-onewaytosource-binding-cannot-work-on-th

Comment: And from the department of the blindingly obvious, the setter must also *exist*; i.e. a property with just a get will exhibit the same issue.

Comment: @ColonelPanic "I've a read only property I need to display in a textbox" tells me that the asker isn't trying to do a two-way binding.  I think he hadn't specified the binding mode and so it defaulted to TwoWay.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

It's hard to guess without code, but you should be able to set the BindingMode to OneWay.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

or from code:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
```

Comment: Yep, "Mode=OneWay" == Read Only; "Mode=OneWayToSource" == Write Only

Comment: Please note that in .NET 4.0 there's a "bug" that OneWayToSource also does a get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967667/wpf-net-4-onewaytosource-binding-to-write-only-property-works-on-some-machine

Comment: Also, for TwoWay Binding on Settings see http://stackoverflow.com/a/845033/194717

Comment: This together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870893/wpf-app-crashes-outside-of-visual-studio solved my problem.  Thanks!  One thing remains unclear: Why does my app run fine within Visual Studio despite this issue?