# InvalidOperationException - A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm using the MVVM pattern and am receiving the following when i run my app

InvalidOperationException
A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Options' of type 'ViewModel.SynergyViewModel'.

I have commented all my source out in my view model and have traced this back to a check box.  If i comment out the the checkbox or the properity in my view model the app runs, minus the functionality.  Below i have listed the code for my checkbox and the property within the viewmodel.

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0,5,5" IsChecked="{Binding Options}" Content="Options"/>
```

```
private bool _Options;
public bool Options
{
    get
    {
        return _Options;
    }
    private set
    {
        if (_Options == value)
            return;

        _Options = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Options");
    }
}
```

System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Options' of type 'ViewModel.MyViewModel'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.CheckReadOnly(Object item, Object info)
  InnerException:

Any ideas on what i'm what i'm missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590269/a-twoway-or-onewaytosource-binding-cannot-work-on-the-read-only-property)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Either make your setter public or explicitly set the [`Binding.Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx) to `OneWay`.

Comment: If you're developing a .net 4.0 WPF project on a machine with .net 4.5 installed, you will not run into this error during development! Microsoft needs to fix this.

Comment: It's so strange that I'm getting the same error with an internal setter... I would have assumed an internal setter would be allowed, but strangely not.

Comment: I wish this answer specified HOW to set the Binding.Mode to OneWay - where do I do this? In the set?

Comment: IsChecked="{Binding Options, Mode=OneWay}"

Answer (score 3):

Your setter is private, either specify the binding to be mode OneWay or remove the private from the setter

Answer (score 0):

In my absolutely stupid case, I have forgotten to define a setter for a property, making it, well, read-only. Just my 2 cents for those who work too late.

Answer (score 0):

**For those who find this without using `PropertyChanged`**

Regardless of whether `PropertyChanged` is used, this exception is also thrown when you have a calculated property (without setter) and the user tries to edit the column. Setting the whole DataGrid to `IsReadOnly="True"` or just the column to ReadOnly is enough then.